# MYSQL - Dynamically Query Generation

Tags: mysql

```
  SELECT table_name,REPLACE(RIGHT(table_name,2),'0','') 
    FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.tables 
   WHERE table_name LIKE '%Report%'
     AND REPLACE(RIGHT(table_name,2),'0','') 
 BETWEEN MONTH('2018-06-05') 
     AND MONTH('2018-08-18') ;

Table list :

Report_201806
Report_201807
Report_201808
```

I need create the Dynamic Query for which i have been fetching list of tables .The Number of tables may be increased or decreased based on date .

```
Expect Result :

    Select a.*,B.*,C.*
      From Report_201806 a 
Inner Join Report_201807 b 
        On a.id=b.id 
Inner Join Report_201808 c 
        On a.id=c.id And b.id=c.id
```

Comment: pls create dummy date on http://sqlfiddle.com and share the fiddle link

Comment: This kind of problem is symptomatic of poor design. I would encourage you to look at proper partitioning.

Comment: OK thanks for your suggestion.